# Objective-C "class prototyping"

Tags: objective-c, prototyping

In C++, you can sort of "prototype" a class in a header file, and actually include it in the implementation;

```
//...
class Bar;

class Foo{
    public:
        Foo();
        Bar* getBar();
};
//...
```

Is there a way to do this in Objective-C?

Comment: What's the real world situation where you want to do this?

Comment: this is called "forward declaration"